# SQL Express concat while condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, string-aggregation

My table looks something like this (with 7500 rows):

```
UserName     Company
Eduard       Google
Alex         Google
Mark         Google
Silvia       Microsoft
```

Any I need it to look like this:

```
UserName             Company
Eduard, Alex, Mark   Google
Silvia               Microsoft
```

Any Idea how to achieve this? I am using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2017 you can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(UserName,', ') AS UserNames, Company
FROM @t
GROUP BY Company
```